# How to find git log messages with more than one line?

Tags: git, grep

I want to use `git log` in a project to view only the commits that have more than one line in their commit messages (i.e. they have a longer description).  What is the best way to go about this?

I tried `git log --grep='\n\n'`, and it came up with *a* list of commits with more than one line, but it was not a complete list.  (I went back through some of the complete log manually and quickly found commits with multiline messages that were not output by my command.)

I then also tried `git log --grep='\n\r\?\n'`, just in case there are Windows-style line endings in some of the commits (I'm using `msysgit`, so it might be possible?), but it came up with the same output as the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work for me (on Linux):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%H<msgst>%b<msge>' \
| fgrep -v '<msgst><msge>' | fgrep '<msgst>' | cut -b1-40 \
| git log --stdin --no-walk
```

Basically: print commit hashes and commit  message body (minus the subject line) wrapped in some uncommon strings, exclude lines where such body is empty (e.g. commits without newlines in the messages), then take just the first lines (those with commit hash at the beginning), and print only the hashes.

Comment: Why `fgrep` instead of plain `grep`?

Comment: @vergenzt: `fgrep` is an alias of `grep -F` that just searches for plain string. I use it because I'm too lazy to think whether `<` is special in the particular regexp variant grep uses. Of course, you can use any grep you wish provided that you adjust it to catch your delimiters.

Comment: Ohh, gotcha.  I had looked in the documentation at `-f`, which is to use a pattern file, and I was quite confused... `-F` makes sense, though.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working.  I used: `git log --format='%H!!!%b@@@' | grep -v '!!!@@@' | grep '!!!' | cut -b1-40 | git log --stdin --no-walk` and it worked fine.  Could you add the `git log --stdin` at the end, for posterity?  It took me a bit to figure that out from the docs.

Comment: Actually, a shorter version: `git log --format='%H!!!%b@@@' | grep '!!![^@]' | cut -b1-40 | git log --std-in --no-walk`.

Comment: I suggest this version: `git log --format='%H%x09%x09%x09%b' | egrep '^[0-9a-f]{40}\t\t\t.' | cut -f1` where `grep` keeps a line if it starts with a commit ID followed by 3 tabs – extremely unlikely to appear in a commit message body, and the tab character happens to be the default field delimiter for `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

For some extra context:

What’s happening when you use `--grep='\n\n'` is that `\n` is not special so it just means `n`:

You are getting the same results as with `--grep='nn'`.

---

As to your actual question:

Note that `--grep` splits the commit message at newlines and matches the pattern against each substring separately. This means you you cannot write a pattern for `--grep` that can figure out whether it’s matching against a different line than the first.

Additionally, because every commit message ends in a newline, the splitting always yields at least one completely empty substring. This means *every* commit matches `--grep='^$'`.

Therefore, there is absolutely no way of using `--grep` to limit `git log`’s output to commits with a multiline message.

---

So the only way of doing it is with the approach given in [che’s answer](/a/11829856/9410). As I commented there, I suggest this particular form:

```sh
git log --format='%H%x09%x09%x09%b' \
| egrep '^[0-9a-f]{40}\t\t\t.' \
| cut -f1 \
| git log --stdin --no-walk   # or whatever
```

In this version, `grep` keeps lines that start with a commit ID followed by 3 tabs followed by any character (i.e. not followed by nothing, i.e. those are commits of interest). This pattern is extremely unlikely to appear in a commit message body, does not require a second `grep` to filter out commit message body lines, and the tab character also happens to be the default field delimiter for `cut` so that’s shorter too.